# Integral from inverse Gaussian process

Tags: integration, levy-processes

By Mathematica I know that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{\infty}_{0}(1-e^{i\theta x})x^{-3/2}e^{-\frac{b^{2}x}{2}}dx = -b+\sqrt{b^{2}-2i\theta}$$

but unfortunately I cannot compute it analytically. Does anyone have an idea how to bite that problem?

I got that integral from the triplet in the Levy-Khintchine formula calculation for inverse Gaussian process in "Introductory Lectures on Fluctuations of Levy Processes with Applications" by A.E. Kyprianou, where author in excercise 1.7 ask to show that $\int^{\infty}_{0}(1-e^{i\theta x})\Pi(dx) = \psi(\theta)$, where $\psi$ is the characteristic exponent and $\Pi$ is Levy measure.

As a hint, author recommends to use identity

$\int^{\infty}_{0}(1-e^{ir})r^{-\alpha -1}dr = - \Gamma(-\alpha)e^{-i\pi\alpha/2}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: *Hint.* For $\operatorname{Re}(a)>0$, $\operatorname{Re}(b)>0$, and $\operatorname{Re}(s)>-1$, we have $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}(e^{-ax}-e^{-bx})\,\mathrm{d}x=\Gamma(s)(a^{-s}-b^{-s}).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, from that identity it is trivial. Do you have any reference to the prove of that identity?

Comment: @Mozqrt It follows directly from the definition of the Gamma function from just expanding and separating it into two integrals and letting $u=ax$ on the first, and $u=bx$ on the second.